# Problema al enviar datos desde formulario de contacto PHP y HTML

Tags: php, html

¡Hola a todos!, estoy haciendo un pequeño proyecto escolar en el cual tengo un formulario de contacto que debe enviar datos de contacto a un correo en especifico, todo esto lo intento realizar con el método POST pero no llegan los datos al correo receptor ni en bandeja de spam, si pudieran ayudarme se los agradecería mucho.

Adjunto los códigos a continuación:

**Código del archivo Contacto PHP:**

```
<?php
$destino= "xxxx@gmail.com";
$nombre= $_POST["nombre"];
$correo= $_POST["correo"];
$telefono= $_POST["telefono"];
$mensaje= $_POST["mensaje"];
$contenido = "Nombre: ". $nombre . "\nCorreo: ". $correo . "\nTelefono: ". $telefono . "\nMensaje: ". $mensaje;
mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);

header("Location:index.php");
?>
```

**Código del formulario *HTML*:**

```
<form class="formulario"  method="POST" action="enviarContacto.php" >
    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="nombre" id="nombre" placeholder="Nombre" value=''>

    <input type="text" REQUIRED name="correo" id="correo" placeholder="Correo"  value=''>

    <input type="tel" REQUIRED name="telefono" id="telefono" placeholder="Teléfono" value=''>

    <textarea  rows="7" cols="30" name="mensaje" id="mensaje" placeholder="Escriba su mensaje aquí" REQUIRED ></textarea><br>  

    <button class="LoginButton" type="submit" value=''>Enviar</button>
</form>
```

**Estos son los errores al ejecutar el archivo *PHP* directamente:**

> Notice: Undefined index: nombre in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 5
>
> Notice: Undefined index: correo in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 6
>
> Notice: Undefined index: telefono in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 7
>
> Notice: Undefined index: mensaje in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 8
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php:5) in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 13

Comment: Muestranos el contenido de **enviarContacto.php**

Comment: En la pregunta por favor

Comment: ya lo he puesto  pero no se porque no se visualiza

Comment: Falta un espacio entre el método y action que podría estar haciendo inválido tu formulario, corrige así y prueba si funciona: `method="POST" action="enviarContacto.php"` Luego, tienes un función in line que no muestras en la pregunta, no sabemos qué ocurre en esa función. Supongo que estás enviando el formulario correctamente, con datos y que esa función no modifica nada ...

Comment: ya lo corregi A. Cedano pero sigue igual.

Comment: sinceramente yo desconozco acerca de el lenguaje php y tome parte de un ejemplo, pero al parecer esta incompleto. ¿que puedo hacer ?

Comment: Pero, pregunto: ¿gestionas el envío del formulario vía Javascript? Tú tienes esto: `<button class="LoginButton" onclick="submit" value=''>Enviar</button>` Ese `onclick` estaría indicando que se llamará a una función declarada como `submit` en Javascript... ¿Existe esa función `submit` en tu Javascript? Si no la hay prueba a poner tu botón de envío así: **`<button class="LoginButton" type="submit">Enviar</button>`**

Comment: no solo puro php

Comment: ya lo modifique pero sigue igual sin que los datos lleguen a su destino, y alejecutar directamente el php enviarContacto siguen saliendo los mensajes de indice no definido.

Comment: Es normal que ejecutar el archivo directamente haga eso, porque no estás mandando datos. Para que los datos lleguen debes llenar el formulario y enviarlo. ¿Probaste llenando el formulario con datos y pulsando en el botón enviar?  Si así no funciona pulsa en [edit] y pon cómo tienes ahora el formulario.

Comment: ya lo puse  A. Cedano

Comment: Puedes poner un `var_dump($_POST);` en el archivo  `enviarContacto.php` y luego pruebas a llenar y enviar el formulario **pulsando en el botón Enviar** y debería recibir los datos. Modifica el archivo poniendo el `var_dump` y dinos qué ocurre.

Comment: ya lo puse pero sale lo siguiente :    array(4) { ["nombre"]=> string(7) "Juanita" ["correo"]=> string(14) "m123@gmail.com" ["telefono"]=> string(8) "98765432" ["mensaje"]=> string(17) "mensaje de prueba" }
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php:4) in /storage/ssd2/518/16259518/public_html/PaginaPrueba3/enviarContacto.php on line 13

Comment: los datos del formulario no me llegan a mi correo es lo que estoy buscando hacer. desconozco del tema y por eso es que estoy solicitando ayuda.

Comment: La salida del `var_dump` indica que el problema de los Undefined index ya se resolvió. Ahiora, en tu función `mail()` debes indicar a quien va dirigido el correo. Por otra parte, hay también otro problema, porque antes del `header("Location:index.php");` se están enviando encabezados desde otra parte. Pulsa en [edit] y coloca el código del archivo completo para ver dónde se están enviando esos encabezados.

Answer (score 0):

por lo menos debe llevar el header de From  o modificarlo en php.ini

```
 mail($destino, "Contacto", $contenido);
```

.
ejemplo:

```
$headers = 'From: Your name <xxxx@gmail.com>' . "\r\n";
mail($destino, $mensaje, $contenido, $headers);
```

También puedes utilizar la librería
https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

espero te ayude!

Comment: buenas noches. una pregunta, Aunque tenga un destino definido debo agregar  el $headers o como?

Comment: Hola, una cosa es el destinatario y en el From de cabecera va el "desde":  Cuando se envía un correo, este debe contener una cabecera From. Puede establecerse con el parámetro additional_headers, o puede definirse un valor predeterminaro en php.ini.

Si no se realiza esta acción se obtendrá un mensaje de error similar a Warning: mail(): "sendmail_from" not set in php.ini or custom "From:" header missing (Advertencia: mail(): "sendmail_from" no establecido en php.ini o falta la cabecera personalizada "From:"). La cabecera From también establece Return-Path bajo Windows.

Answer (score -2):

no sé si ya lo habrás solucionado pero tengo un problema similar y el warning se me fue de una manera ridícula. Aparentemente php es muy quisquilloso con los espacios en blanco.Para solucionar esto pegué el código en el editor de texto Atom  y luego puse en el menú Packages->Whitespace->Remove Trailing Whitespace y por lo menos eso se solucinó.
Ahora estoy luchando con los errores de index al igual que los que pusiste arriba.